# Keeping back stack on configuration change in dynamic app with single activity

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

My app has no XML. It is all made of Java code dynamically. In the app, when in portrait mode, only one screen is visible - a fragment which changes inside a `FrameLayout` inside a single activity. When rotating, the same single activity gets another `FrameLayout` (on the right) for displaying two halves of the screen.

The app itself has a user flow of fragments.
If a user rotate to landscape, the menu (`ListFragment`) is shown in the left half of the screen, and the right half of the screen is empty.

If a user selects one item from the `ListFragment` (on the left), the right `FrameLayout` shows another `ListFragment` or FormFragment (this depends of JSON response). If another list shows in the right `FrameLayout`, if a user selects one item from that list, now this `ListFragment` goes in left `FrameLayout`, and in the right is FormFragment etc.

So it is a "fine dance" of replacing the fragments inside left and right FrameLayouts which is then placed on the backstack. So if a user rotate the screen in some moment, I need a way to preserve that backstack, so the user can go back through a backstack when in landscape.

Also, if a user is in portrait mode, I also need a way to preserve that backstack when he rotates from landscape to portrait.

**The problem:**

How to retain (keep) the backstack of all the fragments, if a user rotates screen from portrait to landscape, and vice versa, so he can go back like it was no change at all.

Is it possible to achieve this in Android? I've tried with setRetainInstance() but I've also read that it is not the way if you want to work with backstack, and also I'm very new to all this, so if anyone can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addToBackStack()` method for adding fragment transaction to back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

Code snippet :

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace({your_Fragment_view});
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Don't forget to do the addToBackStack(null) so your previous state will be added to the backstack allowing you to go back with the back button.

Reference link - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes, I am using that when replacing fragments in runtime. My app works fine if it is in portrait or landscape mode, only thing is that I need a way how to preserve whole backstack during the configuration change.